# Is it possible to have a load test with Visual Studio 2019 with .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, load-testing, .net-core-3.0

I need to update my load test project from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET Core 3.0, but have tried a number of suggestions including updating VS 2019 to v16.5.236... and made sure I installed .NET Core 3.0 and still not seeting in in VS 2019?

Any suggestion for me?  Thanks in advance for your help!
Tien
[image]

Comment: [It's there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/load-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1), just install it.

Comment: Can you show me, @Hans Passant?  Thanks.

Comment: I've followed the "It's there" reference but it has nothing for .NET Core framework at all let alone 3.0.  Thanks.